# Is there a simple way to access a single trace from a Plotly figure containing multiple traces (i.e. splom) in Python?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I would like to access a trace of a Plotly figure with multiple subplots to plot that trace individually. For example I would like to do the following:

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_matrix(df)

sub_fig = fig.GET_ME_A_TRACE(row=1, col=1)
sub_fig.show()
```

Is this possible/feasible in such a way?

Comment: It may be possible to use the data for other graphs if you check the original data in the `plotly` graphs. 'splom' may or may not be possible. Please check the contents of `fig.data` first to get an idea of the structure.

Comment: Yes, I know that you can access the data of a figure. But that's most of the time way more complex than simply utilizing the original source data (i.e. the pandas dataframe). That's why I wrote "simple".

Comment: @oskarszarowicz unfortunately no. But I haven't investigated much further since then, so maybe something has come up in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that plotly figure has trace names "0", "1", "2"

```py
fig.for_each_trace(
lambda trace: trace.update(visible=True) if trace.name in ["0", "1", "2"] else (trace.update(visible=False)),
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I am hesitant to mark this answered, as this only sets the traces visibility. When working with complex plots and you only want to continue with one trace, this adds a lot of overhead (all the data that is contained in the plot but not shown). Ideally, I would like to extract one trace only in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `select_traces` method of `Figure`? It seems like exactly what you need.

For example:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_matrix(df)

sub_fig = fig.select_traces(row=1, col=1)
sub_fig.show()
```

Besides taking rows and columns, it also has a `selector` input, which allows for more complex querying based off things like name. See here:
https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html#plotly.graph_objects.Figure.select_traces

Comment: Unfortunately, your example does not work for me. Plotly Express seems to work a little differently here. However, it works with `make_subplots` using something like `fig2.add_trace(list(fig.select_traces(row=1, col=1))[0])`

Any idea how this could work with Plotly Express?